# Regex to get/replace strings in between two character sets in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string containing external url links like

```
.listView a.toggle::after { content: " "; background: url("/test/images/up_small.svg") center center no-repeat; }
```

I want to grab the text between the url tags like

```
/test/images/up_small.svg
```

I tried like

```
a.split(new RegExp("[^(url)\(\".*\"]"))
```

but it did not work.

**How can I get the external url and if needed replace the same with something else? in JavaScript**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can search using this regex with 2 capture groups:

```bash
(.* url\(")[^"]+(".*)
```

And replace using `$1http://example.com$2` where `http://example.com` is replacement.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uBB49E/1)

**Code:**

```js
var s = '.listView a.toggle::after { content: " "; background: url("/test/images/up_small.svg") center center no-repeat; }';

var r = s.replace(/(.* url\(")[^"]+(".*)/, '$1http://example.com$2');

console.log(r);
```

Comment: I tried using `s.search(new RegExp(/(.* url\(")[^"]+(".*)/))`. It did not give me the correct index though. Also s.split.. does not give me the in between text . I understand replace is working, but extraction how do I do ?

Comment: To match URL use: `.match(/ url\("([^"]+)"/` and grab capture group #1